# Hide specific empty row in gridlayout

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have implemented a view with a gridlayout in which two listviews are loaded...in some cases one of the two listviews can be empty (no data)...I hide the listview with an ngif but the set space of the row remains visible...is there a way to collapse a specific row?

```
<ScrollView> 
<GridLayout rows="10, 200, 200, 10" columns="*">
<div *ngIf="some variables">
<RadListView row="1">...</RadListView></div>
<RadListView row="2">...</RadListView>
</GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i'd like to collapse row 1 if ngif is false...now I hide the listview but a space of 200px remains...

Comment: please add your code details and specify the exact problem you are facing

Comment: You can also "binding" the "rows property": `<GridLayout [rows]="condition? '10,200,200,10' : '0,200,200,10'">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<GridLayout rows="10, auto, 200, 10">`. This way when `row="1"` is hidden, its space is also collapsed and taken over by the row below.

Here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nativescript-stackblitz-templates-hmrqdk?file=src/app/item/items.component.html) demonstrating this.

```
<GridLayout rows="auto, auto, *">
  <Button row="0" (tap)="toggle()" text="Toggle"></Button>
  <Label row="1" *ngIf="show" text="Hello"></Label>
  <ListView row="2" [items]="items">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
      <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]">
        <Label [text]="item.name" class="text-lg text-gray-500 p-4"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
  </ListView>
</GridLayout>
```